# How can I type hint an attribute in Python 3.5?

Tags: python, attributes, type-hinting

I have a class where I want the initial value of an attribute to be `None`:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_attribute = None
```

How can I add type hinting, so that the IDE understands that `some_attribute` is usually of the type `AnotherClass`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In Python 3.5, you have to write

```
self.some_attribute = None  # type: AnotherClass
```

Since Python 3.6, new type hinting syntax was added for variables ([PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/)):

```
self.some_attribute: AnotherClass = None
```

This will probably make every type-checking system complain, because None is in fact not an instance of AnotherClass. Instead, you can use [`typing.Union[None, AnotherClass]`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#union-types), or the shorthand:

```
from typing import Optional
...
self.some_attribute: Optional[AnotherClass] = None
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.10+ uses pipe sign `|` which many languages use as the or operator ([PEP 604](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/)) to denote `Typing.Union`.

So…

`self.some_attribute: AnotherClass|None = None`

More concise, no `Typing` import needed.

FWIW, generally 3.10 also does away with many built containers needing Typing imports:  `list[int]`, not `List[int]` (which still works).

Note: if using forward declarations, `Optional["AnotherClass"]` is still needed, pipe doesn't work.

Also pipe handles more than None, since it’s a shorthand for `Typing.Union`:

`some_attribute: AnotherClass|YetAnotherClass|None`