# In Python, how do I type hint 'has attribute'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

**Consider this contrived example;**

```
@dataclass
class A:
    name: str = "John"
    ....

@dataclass
class B:
    name: str = "Doe"
```

Q: **How do I type hint an object that has an attribute, such as the following?**

```
def print_name(obj: HasAttr['name'])
    print(obj.name)
```

I understand the SO rule on showing what you have tried. The best I can offer is that I've searched the docs; [Pep526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/), [PythonSheets](https://www.pythonsheets.com/notes/python-typing.html), [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), and am aware of this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40173982/how-can-i-type-hint-an-attribute-in-python-3-5). None seem to help (or maybe I missed it.)

[Edit] I recognize that you can get there with inheritance, but I don't want to go that route.

Comment: Also: [How can I use static checking to ensure an object has a certain method/attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64185810/7851470)

Comment: Thanks, @Georgy - knowing what to search for is often the hardest. I'm tempted to leave this question up considering I couldn't find the other answers easily (and this isn't my first rodeo.) I suspect others might come upon this question before they might see the others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, what you are describing is structural typing. This is distinct from the class-based nominal subtyping that the python typing system is based on. However, structural subtyping is sort of the statically typed version of Python's dynamic duck typing.

[Python's typing system](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/) allows a form of this through `typing.Protocol`.

An example, suppose we have a Python module, `test_typing.py`:

```
from typing import Protocol
from dataclasses import dataclass

class Named(Protocol):
    name: str


@dataclass
class A:
    name: str
    id: int


@dataclass
class B:
    name: int

@dataclass
class C:
    foo: str


def frobnicate(obj: Named) -> int:
    return sum(map(ord, obj.name))


frobnicate(A('Juan', 1))
frobnicate(B(8))
frobnicate(C('Jon'))
```

Using mypy version 0.790:

```
(py38) juanarrivillaga@Juan-Arrivillaga-MacBook-Pro ~ % mypy test_typing.py
test_typing.py:28: error: Argument 1 to "frobnicate" has incompatible type "B"; expected "Named"
test_typing.py:28: note: Following member(s) of "B" have conflicts:
test_typing.py:28: note:     name: expected "str", got "int"
test_typing.py:29: error: Argument 1 to "frobnicate" has incompatible type "C"; expected "Named"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```