# How to draw UML diagram for python with abstract classes

Tags: python, inheritance, uml, abstract-class, class-diagram

I have a base Abstract class `Function` and child classes `ExpFunction`, `LogFunction`, and `CubicFunction`. I have Main class as below:

```
class Main:
    """
    Main class to run the program
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.f_1 = ExpFunction("Exponential", 0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -5.0, 0)
        self.f_2 = LogFunction("Logarithmic", 0.0001, 0.05, 3.0, 10.0, 0.001)
        self.f_3 = CubicFunction("f3", 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, -3.0, 4.0, -5.0, 0.0001)

    def _run(self):
        """
        Run the program
        """
        print("Starting the program...\n\n")
        self.f_1.print_function()
        self.f_1.find_roots()

        self.f_2.print_function()
        self.f_2.find_roots()

        self.f_3.print_function()
        self.f_3.find_roots()

        print("Program finished.")

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
        self._run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
    main()
```

I have drawn the following diagram:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UotAt.png)

[image]

Is this correct diagram?

Comment: Take a look at this to create a UML diagram automatically from source code: [What's the best way to generate a UML diagram from Python source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260165/whats-the-best-way-to-generate-a-uml-diagram-from-python-source-code)

Comment: @JorgeLuis This is a good idea. However tools like pylint also have a number of shortcommings where some associations are not correctly detected. In this particular case, it may not correctly detect that f_1, f_2 and f_3 are in reality meant to be Function, even if the instances are more specialized (which is also btw the weakness in OP's diagram)

Comment: Where in the question do I find an abstract class at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Abstract classes and operations

We cannot say if `Function` and its 3 specialization are correct, since we don't have the corresponding code. But if it is abstract, it should be shown as such in the diagram (italic class name), and so should be the abstract operations (aka member functions in python) that you have explicitly defined in each of the 3 specialization.

### Is this the real design?

In your code snippet, `Main` has   `f_1`, `f_2` and `f_3`. Your diagram says that these are always `LogFunction`, `ExpFunction` and `CubicFunction`.
Considering the current code, this is not wrong. Here the diagram (simplified version) automatically generated by pyreverse (note that the pyreverse layout is not so nice as yours, and it also doesn't show the abstract items in italic):

[image]

However, nothing prevents you from changing `f_1`, `f_2` and `f_3` to  be other kinds of `Function`, for example by adding the following reassignment in at the end of `_run()`:

```
    self.f_2 = CubicFunction(...)
    self.f_2.print_function()
```

You could also chose to initialize them differently, because **you use only their common abstract interface**. You could therefore decide to show  `Main` associated with 3 `Function`, and leave it to the runtime to decide which of the subclass to instantiate:

[image]

This diagram would also be correct. Moreover it corresponds to a more powerful design that better use the abstraction and polymorphism that your abstract class allows.

Since your code does not give a [type hint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40173982/3723423) and since python is  dynamically typed, we cannot tell which of the two alternative design is the one you wanted. Only you know what you intended to do.

To generate the second diagram with pyreverese, I updated the initialization to use type hints; this makes the design intent more explicit in the code:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.f_1:Function = ExpFunction()
    self.f_2:Function = LogFunction()
    self.f_3:Function = CubicFunction()
```

*As a side remark, feel free to remove the shared aggregation (hollow diamond): UML does not define any semantic for shared aggregation (since more than 20 years!) : a simple association would express exactly the same thing.*